# Angular Firestore - This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire, permission-denied

I am creating a project using Angular and Firebase.
Everything was working properly locally and live.

Suddenly on live site I am facing below firestore database access error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJLTf.png)

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.13.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project **.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

But I am able to access firestore database from localhost,
On localhost everything is working properly, but after deploying an new build on live site its not working and throwing same console error.

Do we have any solution ?

Comment: Make sure add the deployment domain name in your firebase console

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.